# How to return a list of all strings that contains a given hashtag?

Tags: python

Here is my code so far:
1st block - Tweet class,
2nd block - input list of tweets,
3rd block - function I am trying to get to work.
4th block - the expected output

```py
class Tweet:
    """Tweet class."""

    def __init__(self, user: str, content: str, time: float, retweets: int):
        """
    Tweet constructor.

    :param user: Author of the tweet.
    :param content: Content of the tweet.
    :param time: Age of the tweet.
    :param retweets: Amount of retweets.
    """
        self.user = user
        self.content = content
        self.time = time
        self.retweets = retweets
```

```
tweet1 = Tweet("@realDonaldTrump", "Despite the negative press covfefe #bigsmart", 1249, 54303)
tweet2 = Tweet("@elonmusk", "Technically, alcohol is a solution #bigsmart", 366.4, 166500)
tweet3 = Tweet("@CIA", "We can neither confirm nor deny that this is our first tweet. #heart", 2192, 284200)
tweets = [tweet1, tweet2, tweet3]
```

```
def filter_by_hashtag(tweets: list, hashtag: str) -> list:
    """
  Filter tweets by hashtag.

  Return a list of all tweets that contain given hashtag.

  :param tweets: Input list of tweets.
  :param hashtag: Hashtag to filter by.
  :return: Filtered list of tweets.
  """
    import re
    filtered_lst = []
    hashtag = re.compile(r'#\w+')
    for tweet in tweets:
        if hashtag in re.findall(r'#\w+', tweet.content):
            filtered_lst.append(tweet)
        else:
            break
    return filtered_lst

print(filter_by_hashtag(tweets, "#bigsmart"))
```

```
filtered_lst = [("@realDonaldTrump", "Despite the negative press covfefe #bigsmart", 1249, 54303), ("@realDonaldTrump", "Despite the negative press covfefe #bigsmart", 1249, 54303)]
```

I have tried a lot of regex library operations but somehow, the list that is being returned in the filtered_by_hashtag function is always empty, I know the problem is in the if clause inside the for loop, but I can't wrap my head around the problem still ..

Comment: Have you tried removing else statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need a regex for this -- Python's basic `in` operator will do the trick.

```
from typing import List

def filter_by_hashtag(tweets: List[Tweet], hashtag: str) -> List[Tweet]:
    return [t for t in tweets if hashtag in t.content]
```